# How can I save a total score in localstorage each time a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I've built a small game using checkboxes with images. When the user comes across the item in the picture they select the checkbox and the message changes on screen.  Because this is a tourist guide website and game, the user will leave the page to look at other pages, selecting the pictures as they come across the item.  Therefore I needed to save the checked boxes in localstorage so that the data persists.  I have some javascript that dsave the checked boxes.

Each picture has a value and when the image is clicked it adds to an overall total.  I can't get this total to persist if the page is refreshed or closed and reopened.

My javascript for calculating the total and storing the checkboxes is below.

```js
$('.dp-spotter-switch input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent('.dp-spotter-switch').removeClass('spotter-scale');

    } else {
        $(this).parent('.dp-spotter-switch').addClass('spotter-scale');
    }
});

function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('getScoreLabel').style.display = "block";
}


// Total values

function totalIt() {
    var input = document.getElementsByName("product");
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i].checked) {
            total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("total").value = "" + total.toFixed(0);
}

// Store checkbox state

(function () {

    var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        var box = boxes[i];
        if (box.hasAttribute("store")) {
            setupBox(box);
        }
    }

    function setupBox(box) {
        var storageId = box.getAttribute("store");
        var oldVal = localStorage.getItem(storageId);
        console.log(oldVal);
        box.checked = oldVal === "true" ? true : false;

        box.addEventListener("change", function () {
            localStorage.setItem(storageId, this.checked);
        });
    }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dp-spotter-container">

    <div class="dp-top-paragraph">
        <p>Some text</p>

        <p>Click on the photos once you have spotted, and at the end click on <strong>Get Your Score</strong> to see how you've done</p>


        <div id="getScoreLabel" style="display:none; text-align: center;">
            <div class="dp-your-score-text" id="getScore">Your Score</div>
            <input value="0" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="total" class="dp-scores dp-floating"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <!-- Spotter 1 -->
    <div class="dp-switch-container">
        <label class="dp-spotter-switch">
            <img class="dp-spotter-img" src="image.jpg">
            <input type="checkbox" name="product" value="3" id="cb1" class="spotter-check" onclick="totalIt()" store="checkbox1">
            <span class="dp-spotter-slider"></span>
            <span class="dp-spotter-text-label">Item 1- 3 Points</span>
        </label>
    </div>


    <!-- Spotter 2 -->
    <div class="dp-switch-container">
        <label class="dp-spotter-switch">
            <img class="dp-spotter-img" src="image.jpg">
            <input type="checkbox" name="product" value="3" id="cb2" class="spotter-check" onclick="totalIt()" store="checkbox2">
            <span class="dp-spotter-slider"></span>
            <p class="dp-spotter-text-label">Item 2 - 3 Points</p>
        </label>
    </div>

    <!-- Spotter 3 -->
    <div class="dp-switch-container">
        <label class="dp-spotter-switch">
            <img class="dp-spotter-img" src="image.jpg">
            <input type="checkbox" name="product" value="5" id="cb3" class="spotter-check" onclick="totalIt()" store="checkbox3">
            <span class="dp-spotter-slider"></span>
            <p class="dp-spotter-text-label">ITem 3 - 5 Points</p>
        </label>
    </div>

    <!-- Spotter 4 -->
    <div class="dp-switch-container">
        <label class="dp-spotter-switch">
            <img class="dp-spotter-img" src="image.jpg">
            <input type="checkbox" name="product" value="10" id="cb4ß" class="spotter-check" onclick="totalIt()" store="checkbox4">
            <span class="dp-spotter-slider"></span>
            <p class="dp-spotter-text-label">Item 4 - 10 Points</p>
        </label>
    </div>



    <a href="#getScore" class="dp-getScore" onclick="showDiv()">Get Your Score</a>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a way to add to the existing function for the checkboxes if possible.

Comment: A quick visual inspection shows the JS code seems correct; there's a good chance the problem would be in the HTML file; I would recommend incuding it in the question, too.

Comment: I've added in my html and the rest of my javascript into my question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately we can't use local storage in StackOverflow runnable code snippets, so you'll have to head over to my repl.it to see this working in action.

Since you're using jQuery, I've gone ahead and provided a jQuery solution:

- Used `.attr()` to set the checkbox based on local storage
- Called `totalIt` when showing `showDiv`

If you want to use your existing code, just change `box.checked = oldVal === "true" ? true : false;` to `box.setAttribute('checked', oldVal === "true" ? true : false)` and add `totalIt` to your `showDiv` function

#### Demo

https://repl.it/@AnonymousSB/SO53500148

#### Solution

```
function showDiv() {
   totalIt();
   document.getElementById('getScoreLabel').style.display = "block";
}


// Total values

function totalIt() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("product");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("total").value = "" + total.toFixed(0);
}

// Store checkbox state
function setupBox(box) {
  var storageId = box.attr("store");
  var oldVal    = localStorage.getItem(storageId);
  box.attr('checked', oldVal === "true" ? true : false)

  box.change(function() {
    localStorage.setItem(storageId, this.checked); 
  });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  $( "input[type='checkbox'][store]" ).each(function( index ) {
    setupBox($( this ));
  });
})
```

You can open Chrome Dev Tools, go to Application, and see your local storage

[image: Screenshot of Chrome Dev Tools]

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, unfortunately for some reason this isn't working. As soon as I refresh the page everything resets.  The code I have for storing the checkboxes works great, but I actually need to ensure that the calculated totals also remain when the page is refreshed.

Comment: Thanks this worked great. Unfortunately the awful CMS I'm forced to use kept removing parts of the html required for this so I had to find another workaround, but your code to help me store the total on page refresh worked a charm

Comment: Glad to be of help